# Vectorized L1 loss?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I was reading a paper and it mentioned that they were using *vectorized L1 loss*, what does that mean in terms of coding? Is there any difference from regular L1 loss? From the paper, this is the formula:

[image]

Looking at `Lf`, if I were to code it, wasn't it just look like the regular L1 loss?

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
loss_f = F.l1_loss(D_t, warped * D_t)
loss_f.backward()
```

if so, why the mention of *vectorized L1 loss* specifically? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization is a widely used concept in computer/data science. Here it refers to a method of computing the L1 loss, but the resulting calculation is still the same. Vector math is often used as a method to speed up code, and you can read a bit more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vectorization-in-python/).